# Regex to accept character any special characters around a word

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regex to to accept following

cool
co-ol
(cool
(cool)
[{co-ol

basically i don't care any special characters (no alpha numberic) around cool and also cool can or cannot be without hypen

[here is what I have done so far without hypen](https://regex101.com/r/DcWBwD/3)

Comment: Please show a few examples of what should NOT match.

Comment: Please show your own attempts and give a sample of what did not work as desired for each of your attempts. Your are not asking for somebody to write a regex according to (incomplete) requirements, are you?

Comment: So last example is a fail because there is a `c` (an alpha character) before the first `co-ol`?

Comment: @Andreas I have been attempting it for 4 hours but I am just looking for a better and easy solution. Find what I have did in the description. My bad I did not put what I had previously

Comment: Try [`(?im)^[^a-z0-9]*c-?o-?o-?l[^a-z0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DcWBwD/4)

Comment: @Andreas yr solution accepts only special characters as well.The cool word without or without hyphen is a required

Comment: @hackfield In what way will it accept only special characters, given that `c`, `o`, `o`, and `l` are all required? `c-?` means a `c` optionally followed by a single `-`. The `c` is not optional, only the `-` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more concise regex but try:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]*c-*o-*o-*l[^a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` - means any character than isn't a letter or number, with the quantifier `*` meaning any amount, 0 or more

`-*` - allows any number of hypens, 0 or more

[test with regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SeESCB/3)